# update scrollview text from python function

Tags: python, user-interface, scrollview, kivy, kivy-language

Update: My problem is solved.
My fault is totally misunderstanding kivy, if your variable is changing over time, you have to trigger this on python (e.g clock.schedule).

---

Sorry for my English, it's not my native.

I try to write a Gui for my automation code (checking gmail, reading e-mail, do some simple actions on web). Main Python-selenium code is ready and working well.

My questions is how can i establish a communication between py code and kv code? I'll generate a python text variable, work as an simple event log and I need to update (grow-expand) a label text on kivy side simultaneously.

Comment: Where is MainPanel defined in the .kv?

Comment: Sorry, i just added mising part. I'll try to fix the code for a while, because of this have some crap code, just ignore it please.

Comment: If you want us to help you, the minimum you should do is read [ask], in this post it tells you that for these types of questions you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: please give your .kv a proper format as it is important.